# GetAsyncKeyState does not work at system startup

Tags: winapi, registry, windows-7-x64

Today I am building simple keylogger application (no no no - not for what you are thinking...). I am using GetAsyncKeyState (I know I should use SetWindowsHookEx, but there are not many good tutorials with this - and I suck in WinApi), and have problem with starting my program on autostart. I am adding it to proper registry, and everything works (program starts at startup), but GetAsyncKeyState cannot read any key (it works if I start it manually). Shortened code:

```
HWND Stealth;
if(!AllocConsole()){
    Sleep(1000*5); 
}
while((Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL))==NULL){
    Sleep(1000*5);
}
//ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
char i;
while (keylogger->working){
    for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++){
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){
                         cout << i << endl; // No output here

}}}
```

Why such behaviour exists, and how to avoid it ? Is it something connected with allocing console in early stages of startup of windows ?

Comment: You did not tell us how you started your <strike>malware</strike>program

Comment: Normal double click from windows explorer.

Comment: I'm confused. First of all you said you are using auto start. Now you say that you start it from explorer. Which is it?

Comment: I understanded that you are asking how I am starting it in normal way - but if it goes for autostart I just restart computer - just as I think I should test how it work in autostart :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: Ok, maybe my english is not perfect but I will give another try :) Application works normal when I start It myself by double click form windows explorer, but after I added it to autostart, and restarted computer there is no output from application (only window of app is showing).

Comment: Right. So how did you add to autostart? Describe exactly how you did that.

Comment: cmd -> winreg-> HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS/CURRENTVERSION/RUN-> new -> key

Answer (score 2):

GetAsyncKeyState() only works with the keyboard state of the calling process.  If your intention is to capture keystrokes in other processes, you need to use SetWindowsHookEx() instead, and your hook must be implemented as a DLL so it can be injected into other processes.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that this should not work at all ? It actually works if started manually from windows explorer - it stops working when it starts alongside with windows (via autostart)